# Sum over string column python

Tags: python, string, count

I am struggling to count the size of a team. I have for every individual, the name of the team she belongs to.

[image: what I have]

There are however hundreds of different teams. I want to construct another column that would count the number of individuals that belong to a given team. I have been able to do a similar operation over a numeric column (using .transform(sum) ), but I can't figure out how to do it when counting over strings.

[image: what I want]

Please do let me know if anything is unclear !

Comment: Please _do not_ post links to code. They will age away. Your question should be self-contained; edit the input and output into your question as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do it with Pandas? If so, try:

```
df1['count'] = df1.groupby('team', as_index=False)['team'].transform(lambda s: s.count())
```

Comment: Hi! Yes I am doing it with Pandas and yes I tried that but how do I then add this to my dataframe properly? I tried 

`df1['size_team']= df1['team'].value_counts()'

but it returns a column full of nan